# Threads wating and waking up

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to understand threads better so i am implementing a simple task:

i have 2 classes that implement runnable. Each one is generating 2 random integers from 1 to 10. ClassA is calculating the sum and ClassB the multiplication. Both are doing this job in a loop for 15 secs.

I have another class called General that has 2 static and synchronized methods: setVal and getVal. Each thread calls General.setVal(result) after each calculation/iteration. setVal only sets the value if it is closer to a number than its previous value. getValue only gets the value.

I have a main class that start each thread. Then there is a loop for 20 secs outputting the value set by the threads. so it is just calling getValue and prints it.

I want each thread, after one iteration to wait and notify the other one to make an iteration and so on... How can i do it?

Here is my code:

```
public class Particle1 implements Runnable{

    //private int x;
    private static final int max = 10;
    private static final int min = 1;

    public void run(){
        long t= System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = t+15000;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
           Random rand = new Random();
           int a = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
           int b = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

           int x = a+b;
           System.out.println("P1: "+a+"+"+b+"="+x);
           Gather.setRes(x);
           //i want it here to sleep until the other one wakes it up.
       }
    }

}


public class Particle2 implements Runnable{

    //private int x;
    private static final int max = 10;
    private static final int min = 1;

    public void run(){
        long t= System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = t+15000;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int a = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            int b = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

            int x = a+b;             
            System.out.println("P2: "+a+"+"+b+"="+x);
            Gather.setRes(x);
            //i want it here to sleep until the other one wakes it up.
         }
    }

}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Particle1());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Particle2());
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();


        long t= System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = t+20000;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            System.out.println("Minimum is: "+Gather.getRes());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return;
    }

}


public class Gather {

    public Gather() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private static int res=1000000;

    public static int getRes() {
        return res;
    }

    public synchronized static void setRes(int inres) {
        if(Math.abs(inres-250)<res){
            res = inres;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: do you mean for two threads to work antagonistically? (because that (sort of) defeats the purpose of multithreading!

Comment: A lot of newbies ask how to make two or more threads take turns.  You can create a synchronization object that will do that, but you won't find an object like that in the library because _that's not what threads are for._  Whenever a program has two or more threads that are not allowed to work at the same time, you can make that program simpler (i.e., better) by having just one thread do all the work.  The entire point of threads, is that two or more threads can be doing different things at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Threads is normally an exercise for when you want all threads to run independently, not in lock-step with each other.

However, there are times when threads need to communicate amongst themselves - in which case it is common to use some form of `BlockingQueue` to communicate between them. Here is an example:

```
public class TwoThreads {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("TwoThreads:Test");
    new TwoThreads().test();
  }

  // The end of the list.
  private static final Integer End = -1;

  static class Producer implements Runnable {
    final Queue<Integer> queue;

    public Producer(Queue<Integer> queue) {
      this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          queue.add(i);
          Thread.sleep(1);
        }
        // Finish the queue.
        queue.add(End);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Just exit.
      }
    }

  }

  static class Consumer implements Runnable {
    final Queue<Integer> queue;

    public Consumer(Queue<Integer> queue) {
      this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      boolean ended = false;
      while (!ended) {
        Integer i = queue.poll();
        if (i != null) {
          ended = i == End;
          System.out.println(i);
        }
      }
    }

  }

  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    Thread pt = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
    Thread ct = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));
    // Start it all going.
    pt.start();
    ct.start();
    // Wait for it to finish.
    pt.join();
    ct.join();
  }

}
```

To truly synchronise between two threads you could use the same mechanism but use a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) instead.